# Plotting x value and error bar in y from a data file

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, data, charts

Here are some of the points where first column is the values on x axis and the other two values are lower and upper limits for the error bars in y.

```
data = {{0.50, 0.23161000 10^-08, 0.22145199 10^-08},
        {1.50, 0.45506399 10^-09, 0.26812801 10^-08},
        {2.50, 0.12028299 10^-08, 0.25072699 10^-08},
        {3.50, 0.12711100 10^-08, 0.25351401 10^-08}};
```

Will someone please show me how to plot such points with error bar?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `ErrorListPlots`

First configure the data properly.

```
data = {{0.50, 0.23161000 10^-08, 0.22145199 10^-08},
        {1.50, 0.45506399 10^-09, 0.26812801 10^-08},
        {2.50, 0.12028299 10^-08, 0.25072699 10^-08},
        {3.50, 0.12711100 10^-08, 0.25351401 10^-08}};
erdata = data /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {{x, y}, ErrorBar[z/10]};
```

Division by 10 is for scaling

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
ErrorListPlot[erdata]
```

[image]

You can use `ErrorListPlot[erdata, Joined -> True]` for plotting with line.